# Multiple Results with One Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a more elegant way of doing this sort of thing?  I have a dashboard that I'm trying to populate with information and I just need a few counts.  I'd like to do it all in one query if possible, but this query below just seems silly.  Any recommendations would be appreciated.

```
    select 
UserCount = (
    select count(*) from net_ou 
        inner join art_asset on net_ou.net_ouid = art_asset.net_ouid
        inner join idb_interface on idb_interface.art_asset_id = art_asset.art_asset_id
        inner join nsd_interfacecode on nsd_interfacecode.nsd_interfacecodeid = idb_interface.nsd_interfacecodeid
        inner join nsd_interfacetype on nsd_interfacetype.nsd_interfacetypeid = idb_interface.nsd_interfacetypeid
        where net_ou.displayname = 'abcd' and nsd_interfacecode.code = 1 and nsd_interfacetype.physical = 1),
PrinterCount = (
    select count(*) as PrinterCount from net_ou 
        inner join art_asset on net_ou.net_ouid = art_asset.net_ouid
        inner join idb_interface on idb_interface.art_asset_id = art_asset.art_asset_id
        inner join nsd_interfacecode on nsd_interfacecode.nsd_interfacecodeid = idb_interface.nsd_interfacecodeid
        inner join nsd_interfacetype on nsd_interfacetype.nsd_interfacetypeid = idb_interface.nsd_interfacetypeid
        where net_ou.displayname = 'abcd' and nsd_interfacecode.code = 2 and nsd_interfacetype.physical = 1),
TrunkCount = (
    select count(*) as TrunkCount from net_ou 
        inner join art_asset on net_ou.net_ouid = art_asset.net_ouid
        inner join idb_interface on idb_interface.art_asset_id = art_asset.art_asset_id
        inner join nsd_interfacecode on nsd_interfacecode.nsd_interfacecodeid = idb_interface.nsd_interfacecodeid
        inner join nsd_interfacetype on nsd_interfacetype.nsd_interfacetypeid = idb_interface.nsd_interfacetypeid
        where net_ou.displayname = 'abcd' and nsd_interfacecode.code = 4 and nsd_interfacetype.physical = 1)
```

Comment: What version of sql server? If 2008+, check out GROUPING SETS http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522495.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `CASE` for this:

```
select 
        SUM(CASE WHEN nsd.interfacecode.code = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as UserCount,
        SUM(CASE WHEN nsd.interfacecode.code = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as PrinterCount, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN nsd.interfacecode.code = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as TrunkCount 
    from net_ou 
        inner join art_asset on net_ou.net_ouid = art_asset.net_ouid
        inner join idb_interface on idb_interface.art_asset_id = art_asset.art_asset_id
        inner join nsd_interfacecode on nsd_interfacecode.nsd_interfacecodeid = idb_interface.nsd_interfacecodeid
        inner join nsd_interfacetype on nsd_interfacetype.nsd_interfacetypeid = idb_interface.nsd_interfacetypeid
    where net_ou.displayname = 'abcd' 
    and nsd_interfacetype.physical = 1
```

Comment: Does this have any negative consequences in terms of performance? Offhand, it seems like it might, but I'm no guru.

Comment: @Harper - no, it should actually run substantially faster than the original.  It returns the `JOIN`ed result set once, then evaluates that .code field for each row.

Comment: @Harper Shelby - This will be definitely faster than the original query

Comment: Oh, I knew it would be faster than the original. I was curious as to how it would compare against mine, which doesn't give pretty column names, but puts the counts in the rows of the result.

Comment: @Harper - I suspect it will be faster than yours since you are using a `GROUP BY` which will require a sort.

Comment: Interesting. Might be worth looking at the query plan for more information. Thanks!

Comment: @harper - it will likely depend on indexes for a full analysis.

Answer (score 1):

```
select nsd_interfacecode.code, count(*) from net_ou 
        inner join art_asset on net_ou.net_ouid = art_asset.net_ouid
        inner join idb_interface on idb_interface.art_asset_id = art_asset.art_asset_id
        inner join nsd_interfacecode on nsd_interfacecode.nsd_interfacecodeid = idb_interface.nsd_interfacecodeid
        inner join nsd_interfacetype on nsd_interfacetype.nsd_interfacetypeid = idb_interface.nsd_interfacetypeid
        where net_ou.displayname = 'abcd' and and nsd_interfacetype.physical = 1
group by nsd_interfacecode.code
```

That should give you your values, assuming I didn't miss anything that's different in the queries.